# Get related interests to an interest using ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the following link/request to get the related interests to an interest ID however after few request I've got limited!

https://www.facebook.com/ads/audience-insights/query/?fb_dtsg_ag=**KEY_HERE**&age[0]=18&age[1]=-1&country[0]=US&interests[0]=**INTEREST_ID**&metrics[0]=2&admarket_id=**ID_HERE**&logger_session_id=**SESSION_Key**&__user=**USER_ID**&__a=1&__dyn=**key_HERE**&__req=p&__be=1&__pc=PHASED%3Aufi_home_page_pkg&dpr=1&__rev=**CODE_HERE**&jazoest=**CODE_HERE**&__spin_r=**CODE_HERE**&__spin_b=trunk&__spin_t=**CODE_HERE**

Error :

> for (;;);{"__ar":1,"error":1958125,"errorSummary":"**API rate
>   limited**","errorDescription":"**User has exceeded the API rate limit
>   for the minute/hour/day, or user has been
>   blacklisted.**","transientError":1,"payload":null,"bootloadable":{},"ixData":{},"bxData":{},"gkxData":{},"qexData":{},"lid":"6659351899596611810"}

NOTE: You can generate the same link by going to Audience insight and search for an interest then switch to Page like tab.

**My question : Is there anyway to make the same request via Facebook Graph API?**

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search#interests

Comment: How do you make the request via a single URL?

Comment: Look at the cURL tab in those code examples, that is the closest to “pure HTTP” you will find there. If you need it for a another library, then you should be able to figure the actual request out from there. (Any unknown cURL parameters you can go look up on its man page.)

Comment: I have checked the docs again and it seems you cannot get the related interests using an interest ID you can only search by keyword!